# Exception when calling strcat

Tags: c, strcat

I'm new to C and I need to write JSON to a file.
I literally spent an hour looking for a working way to append an int to a str.

Here is my code:

```
int day = 1;

char strDay = (char) day;
char str[100];
strcpy(str, "Blockchain");
strcat(str, strDay);
```

Everything works well until the strcat call.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm using parson to write my struct to a file. Here's what the JSON file should look like:

```
{
"Blockchain": {
    "Block1": {
        "Day": 2,
        "Transaction1": {
            "ID": 1,
            "Amount": 2
        }
    },
    "Block2": {
        "Transaction2": {
            "ID": 2,
            "Amount": 5
        }
    }
}}
```

To do that, I use the parson lib and it works like that:

```
json_object_dotset_number(root_object, "Blockchain.Block1.Transaction1.ID", tmpTransaction->accountID);
```

I need a way to create mutiple blocks and transactions and that's why I thought of appending the day to the block and the id to the transaction.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: How does parsing JSON require appending an `int` to a string?

Comment: strcat() 2nd arguments is string not single character,

Comment: Oh, so by "parse" you actually mean *generating* JSON?

Comment: "Everything works well until..". OK. And then *what*? If something doesn't work, don't you think it makes sense to tell us what error you are getting?

Comment: yes, I need to write a JSON document from my Blockchain struct. the raised exception is an Access violation reading location 0x00000001

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/charstring/strvschar.html and especially http://c-faq.com/lib/itoa.html.

Comment: Crank up the wanings on your compiler, you have an integer to pointer conversion on that `strcat` call that cannot surely be ignored by any recent compiler.

Comment: See: [ASCIITable](http://www.asciitable.com/) and think about the difference between `1` and `'1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have likely realized, `strcat` only works on strings.  You should investigate `sprintf` and `snprintf`.  For instance:

```
{
  char string[80];
  int dayNumber;

  dayNumber = 27;
  sprintf(string, "\"Block1\": {\n\t\"Day\": %d,\n", dayNumber);
...
```

Obviously, I'm not trying to create your entire string.  Additionally, in no way should this be considered complete code.  Using magic numbers (like an 80 character string buffer) is bad practice. This is just an example.